# ¿Para que sirve Invocable en java?

Tags: java, api

Hasta ahora sólo sé que es una interfaz que tiene los siguientes métodos:

- **invokeMethod()**
- **invokeFunction()**
- **getInterface()**

Pero no entiendo para que sirve cada uno de ellos y en dónde se ocupa exactamente la interfaz Invocable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Este interfaz se usa en maquinas que interpretan otros lenguajes de programación como `javascript`, que por ejemplo se hace con Nashorn.

Imaginate que tienes javascript como:

```
String javascript = "function multiplica(a, b) { return a * b; }\n"
     + "function divide(a, b) { return a / b; }"
```

Con la maquina de script implementas la interfaz `Invocable` para llamar a funciones desde Java con **invokeFunction()**:

```
ScriptEngineManager engineManager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = engineManager.getEngineByName("nashorn");
// cargemos el código para que la maquina lo evalua
engine.eval(javascript);

// la maquina implementa la interfaz Invocable
Invocable js = (Invocable) engine;
// podemos llamar a funciones así:
System.out.println(js.invokeFunction("multiplica",3,5)
// eso imprime 15
```

Ademas podemos crear interfazes en java con **getInterface()** para acceder al script:

```
interface Calculador{
    multiplica(int a, int b);
    divide(int a, int b);
}

// con eso podemos obtener una interfaz de Java del script
Calculador calc = js.getInterface(Calculador.class);
System.out.println(calc.multiplica(2,3));
// imprime 6
System.out.println(calc.divide(8,4));
// imprime 2
```

El ultimo método **invokeMethod()** es parecido a `invokeFunction` pero permite llamar métodos de un objeto:

```
// cargemos un objeto en javascript
Object jsObjeto = engine.eval(new FileReader("Printer.js"));
// llamamos a Printer.print( nombre )
js.invokeMethod(jsObjeto, "print", "foo" );
```

[Documentación de Nashorn en ingles (Oracle)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/nashorn/intro.html#sthref8)

Answer (score 3):

Cuando un motor de *scripts* (el cual implementa  [`javax.script.ScriptEngine`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html)) también implementa, a su vez, la interfaz [`javax.script.Invocable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/script/Invocable.html), significa que puede ejecutar procedimientos, funciones o métodos que  previamente han sido *compilados*.

Es decir, en lugar de utilizar el método `eval` de `javax.script.ScriptEngine`, se puede invocar el procedimiento o función o método directamente desde un programa en Java. Debe tenerse en cuenta que la implementación de la interfaz `Invocable` por un motor de *scripts* es opcional. Antes de invocar algún procedimiento, función o método, se debe comprobar si el motor de scripts es una instancia de esta interfaz, hacer un *cast* a `Invocable`, y a continuación, ejecutar  los métodos de esta interfaz.

Esta interfaz contiene cuatro métodos. Las dos versiones del método `getInterface()` permiten obtener una instancia de una interfaz Java la cual es implementada en un lenguaje de *scripting* (p.ej.: `factorial.js`). El método `invokeFunction()` permite invocar una función de nivel superior (p.ej.: `parseInt()`) escrita en un lenguaje de *scripting*. El método `invokeMethod()` permite invocar métodos de objetos (p.ej.: `obj.toString()`) escritos en un lenguaje de *scripting*.

Si se desea hacer una invocación de este tipo, se pueden​ seguir los siguientes pasos:

1. Verificar primeramente si el motor de *scripts* es *`Invocable`*:

   ```
   ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
   ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("jruby");

   if (engine instanceof Invocable) {
       // Es invocable :-)
   } else {
       // No es invocable :'(
   }
   ```
2. Hacer un *cast* a la referencia de `ScriptEngine` a `Invocable`:

   ```
   Invocable inv = (Invocable) engine;
   ```
3. Evaluar un *script* para que el motor lo compile y guarde el *compilado* para futuras invocaciones:

   ```
   String script = "def sumar(a, b)\n  return a + b\nend";
   engine.eval(script);
   ```
4. Invocar el procedimiento, función o método:

   ```
   Object result = inv.invokeFunction("sumar", 1, 2);
   ```

#### *Ademdum*

Un motor de *scripts* también puede implementar la interfaz [`javax.script.Compilable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/script/Compilable.html) la cual permite compilar *scripts* para su ejecución de manera repetida.

[image: Nashorn]

---

*Referencias*

- Klauer, N. (2008). *InvokingFunctionsExample.java.* Recuperado de https://github.com/klauern/callingruby/blob/master/src/klauer/callingruby/yokoharada/InvokingFunctionsExample.java
- McQueeney, T. (2007). *Introducing the Java scripting API.* Recuperado de https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-javascripting1/
- Sharan, K. (2014). *Scripting in Java : Integrating with Groovy and JavaScript.* Berkeley, CA: Apress.